# How to update record in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller code

```
if($this->input->post('update'))
         {
             $n=$this->input->post('pps_pin');
             $e=$this->input->post('pps_address');
             $m=$this->input->post('stm_shipping_type');
             $a=$this->input->post('tsm_time_slot');
             $b=$this->input->post('pps_price');
             $id=$this->input->post('pps_slid');
         $this->Config_model->updaterecords($n,$e,$m,$id,$a,$b);
         redirect('Admin_ctrl/config/view_pincode_price');
         }
    }
```

model code

```
function updaterecords($n,$e,$m,$id,$a,$b)
    {   
        $id;

        $qr=$this->db->query("UPDATE pincode_price_setup,shipping_type_mst,time_slot_mst SET pps_pin='$n',pps_address='$e',stm_shipping_type='$m',tsm_time_slot='$a',pps_price='$b' WHERE pps_slid='$id'");
        return $qr;
    }
```

Delivery Method and Delivery Time Slot data are same[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This code looks vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also, it'll probably break if any of your input values contain quotes.

Comment: @Vickel codeigniter *can not* take care of SQL injection if the query is built by inserting arguments *directly into the string*.  this code **is** open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Vickel you are incorrect. The links to CI documentation that you provide use query binding by supplying additional arguments to the query method. The code in the post here does not. It constructs the query as a string. CodeIgniter will not escape anything. This code is definitely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code to use codeigniters prepared statements. If I correctly understood relations in your DB, your update records method should looks something like this:

```
function updaterecords($n, $e, $m, $id, $a, $b)
{
    $this->db->set('pps_pin', $n);
    $this->db->set('pps_address', $e);
    $this->db->set('stm_shipping_type', $m);
    $this->db->set('tsm_time_slot', $a);
    $this->db->set('pps_price', $b);
    $this->db->join('shipping_type_mst', 'pincode_price_setup.pps_shipping_type = shipping_type_mst.stm_sqlid');
    $this->db->join('time_slot_mst', 'pincode_price_setup.pps_time_slot = time_slot_mst.tsm_sqlid');
    $this->db->where('pps_slid', $id);
    $this->db->update('pincode_price_setup');
}
```

Friendly tip: give your variables some more meaningful names, it would be much easier to work with variable named $pin than $n.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'stm_shipping_type' in 'field list'

UPDATE `pincode_price_setup` SET `pps_pin` = '751018', `pps_address` = 'Puri', `stm_shipping_type` = 'evening', `tsm_time_slot` = '235', `pps_price` = '26' WHERE `pps_slid` = '7:AM - 5:PM'

Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/giftmate_debasis/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: @ErDebasis I took field names from your code, so you need to change stm_shipping_type to field name which is according to your logic

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```php
//Controller Code
function update_record($id){ 
    $update_array = array(
       'pps_pin' => $this->input->post('pps_pin') ///add fields in array which updated  
    );
    $this->modal_name->update($id,update_array);//pass id & array which want to be update
}
```

```php
//Modal code

function update($id,$array){
    return $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('TABLE_NAME',array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, you want to update records in your database. I will not write it for you. I will show you an example.

This code may not be perfect but it works for my localhost project.

Create a function to update records in your controller.

Example:

```
public function update($id){

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    //create $data array and add your data to array
    $data = array(
        'nazov_divizia'     =>  $this->input->post('nazov')
    );

    //send this $data array with $id to your update function in model
    $this->Divizia_model->updateData($id, $data);

    //you can create flash message if you want
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Údaje upravené');

    //redirect to your controller index function
    redirect(base_url().'divizia');
}
```

Create a function to update the record in your model.

Example:

```
public function updateData($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id_divizia', $id);
    $this->db->update('divizia', $data);
}
```

Comment: there is a big inner join taple so how to update inner join table??

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try This code



function updaterecords($n, $e, $m, $id, $a, $b) {

             $this->db->set('pps_pin', $n);
             $this->db->set('pps_address', $e);
             $this->db->set('stm_shipping_type', $m);
             $this->db->set('tsm_time_slot', $a);
             $this->db->set('pps_price', $b);
             $this->db->where('pps_slid', $id);
             $this->db->update('pincode_price_setup');
             return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
        }
```

Comment: Unknown column 'stm_shipping_type' in 'field list'

Comment: Maybe  that column stm_shipping_type field is not there in your database. recheck the database once.

Answer (score 0):

Once codeigniter model is loaded then its default `update` function works

```
if($this->input->post('update'))
     {
        $data = [
                'pps_pin' => $this->input->post('pps_pin'),
                'pps_address' => $this->input->post('pps_address'),
                'stm_shipping_type' => $this->input->post('stm_shipping_type'),
                'tsm_time_slot' => $this->input->post('tsm_time_slot'),
                'pps_price' => $this->input->post('pps_price'),
                'pps_slid' => $this->input->post('pps_slid'),
            ];
     $this->Config_model->id = $id;
     $this->Config_model->update($data);

     redirect('Admin_ctrl/config/view_pincode_price');
     }
}
```

So I am sure we don't need to define a separate function in model for same purpose.